# Role-based access control in Azure API App

Tags: api, azure, azure-sql-database, rbac

I have the following scenario:

There is an sql database in Azure which contains a table called Contacts. I can access the data from this table with an self-implemented Java API App which is also hosted on Azure.

Now what I want:

A user with RoleA can only see a small set of Contacts when calling the API. And a user with RoleB can see a bigger set of Contacts when using the API. I somehow would define the sets which can be accesses by the users.

What is the best place to implement this Role-bases access control? Can/should I

1. configure that within the Azure portal?
2. Implement this in my Java backend?
3. create users for every role within my SQL database?

Comment: `What is the best place to implement this Role-bases access control?`..I would go with SQL,first step would be to access table to see if he has right access

Answer (score 1):

You should get exactly that behavior by using [Row level security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx).

You can:

1.) Map any/all contacts to users of your app. (You may decide it's simplest to do in a secondary table.)

2.) Implement a predicate which checks which user is logged into the app.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Security.contactAccessPredicate(@ContactID int) 
RETURNS TABLE 
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN SELECT 1 AS isAccessible 
FROM dbo.ApplicationUserContacts --a mapping table  
WHERE  
( 
    -- application users can access only patients assigned to them 
    Contact_ContactID = @ContactID
    AND ApplicationUser_Id = CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'UserId') AS nvarchar(128))  
) 
OR  
( 
    -- DBAs can access all contacts
    IS_MEMBER('db_owner') = 1 
) 
go
```

3.) Bind that predicate to your schemas.

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY Security.contactSecurityPolicy 
    ADD FILTER PREDICATE Security.contactAccessPredicate(PatientID) ON dbo.Contacts, 
    ADD BLOCK PREDICATE Security.contactAccessPredicate(PatientID) ON dbo.Contacts
go
```

I took some guesses at your table naming and how you might name a mapping table.

There's a similar implementation in the [Azure SQL Security Demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-sql-security-sample)

---

To answer your ideas: I don't think 1 would work, 2 would work fine though would be dependent on APP updates for changes to mapping, and 3 wouldn't directly work. The outline I described above will take the user who is logged into the web app to be able to determine which rows were returned.

Comment: Is it possible to implement a similar example in Java? Are there Java libraries for every function you are using in the SQL Security Demo?

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear- the above commands are executed on your database. 

Java should work fine- I don't believe there should be anything too out of the ordinary to do the same approach on Java- though I haven't tried it recently.